# How to base64 encode a $_FILES file on a form post?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

How can I base64 encode a file sent from one page to another via a form `POST`.

The following do not work:

- `base64_encode($_FILES['file'])`
- `base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']))`
- `base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['name']))`

Why don't they work?

What is the correct thing to do to base64 encode the file?

Comment: $_FILES['file'] is not correct - http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Why would you want to encode? Wouldn't you rather want to decode an encoded transmission?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone to check whether the uploaded file matches any other file already in the database

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I don't get it

Comment: You should look in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` assumed that your form field is named "file"

Comment: I'ld store it unencoded as BLOB saving storage space.

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

tmp_name is the file path to the file that is being temporarily stored

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
```

Comment: I tried but got this `Warning: file_get_contents(C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0RC7-\php\tmp\php7BFA.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0RC7-\apache2\htdocs\classupload.php on line 86`

Comment: @Titoxdboss Did you think about adapting to your needs or do you just copy'n'paste 1:1 from the web? Names, checking for existence...

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I don't understand

Comment: @Titoxdboss try moving the file and then encrypting it move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], '::Change to a writeable directory that Apache can write to::').

Comment: To make this a good SO answer you could be more verbose in description, telling what the array keys are, why file will be lost when not copied, what at all `$_FILES` is...

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Like how?